# Query not returning anything

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables: winery and wineType (in wineType I have foreign key for winery, called wineryID). I try get all winery names that produce wine like the one the client selected from drop down list. And I have this function

```
public void ispolniLista()
{
    DataClassesDataContext MyDB = new DataClassesDataContext();
    var id = from wineT in MyDB.WineTypes where wineT.kind == ddlSorti.SelectedItem.Text select new { wineT.wineryID };

     List<int> listaID = id as List<int>;
     List<string> listaIminja = new List<string>();
     try
     {
         foreach (int i in listaID)
         {
             var vname = from w in MyDB.Wineries where w.wineryID == i select new { w.name };
             listaIminja.Add(vname.ToString());
         }
         lstVinarii.DataSource = listaIminja;
         lstVinarii.DataBind();
     }
     catch (NullReferenceException err)
     {
         Console.Write(err.Message);
     }
 }
```

And I have nothing for result, the lstVinarii is empty.

Comment: Is your listaID empty aswell?

Comment: my code is updated now ..just do check its working or not, reply that is work for you or not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

**Note: From your code  Remove new from select, no need to create extra anonymous type that is also one problem**

To avoid comment error write like this

```
  var id = from wineT in MyDB.WineTypes 
where wineT.kind == ddlSorti.SelectedItem.Text 
select wineT.wineryID ;
```

Remove new from select, no need to create extra anonymous type same in below code

---

try

```
List<int> listaID = id.ToList<int>();
```

than remove foreach loop and write like this

```
var listaIminja= (from win MyDB.Wineries
             where listaID .Contains( w.wineryID ) 
            select  w.name ).ToList();
      lstVinarii.DataSource = listaIminja;
      lstVinarii.DataBind();
```

Comment: I get error telling me this "Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to System.Linq.ParallelQuery<int>' "  for List<int> listaID = id.ToList<int>() line

Comment: @Katerina = my code is updated now ..just do check its working or not

Comment: I saw your update, but I still get the error "Cannot convert  Linq.IQueryable<int> to Linq.ParallelQuery<int>"

Answer (score 2):

Where you are casting the result like this:

```
List<int> listaID = id as List<int>;
```

You need to instantiate it so the enumerable is actually enumerated, like this:

```
List<int> listaID = new List<int>(id);
```

However, it would be worth re-writing this to take advantage of joins, because you're going to be popping off a lot of queries with the method above (because you have a query within a loop).

Answer (score 2):

```
List<int> id = ( from wineT in MyDB.WineTypes where wineT.kind == ddlSorti.SelectedItem.Text select  wineT.wineryID ).ToList();
```

Do this !

Comment: thank you, but I still get the error "Cannot convert Linq.IQueryable<int> to Linq.ParallelQuery<int>".

Comment: Don't know what type 'MyDB.WineTypes' is... can you do 'MyDB.WineTypes.AsEnumerable()'  ??